# if i select one value from kendo dropdownlist, same value has to be select in other kendo dropdownlists

Tags: select, kendo-ui

i have multiple kendo dropdownlists in a grid column.If i select a value from top dropdownlist, automatically all other dropdownlist values needs to be selected in same column.i tried some thing in mycode, as a result if select a value from top drodownlist only next dropdownlist value is selecting, other dropdownlists remains same. so please help me on this.

working file.--> http://dojo.telerik.com/IVOWA

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the relevant code here.  You will get better answers, as well as get them faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your dojo

http://dojo.telerik.com/IVOWA/3

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thanks David.it is what exactly i wanted